# Как исправить ошибку system.argumentoutofrangeexception в dataGridView в .Net?

Tags: c#, массивы, .net, datagridview, index

Дело в том, что я создал dataGridView в .Net. У меня есть массив, значения которого я хочу записать во вторую колонку по нажатию кнопки. Для этого я использую код, представленный ниже:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i];
            }
    }
```

Тут у меня возникает ошибка:

```
ошибка system.argumentoutofrangeexception: "индекс за пределами диапазона. индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. имя параметра: index"
```

Уже все форумы прошерстил в поисках ответа. Помогите пожалуйста, очень срочно нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-add-column.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
> ```

Как по-твоему, сколько в гриде строк после этой команды?

> ```
> dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i];
> ```

А к какой ты обращаешься вот тут?

Comment: Это больше комментарий, чем ответ.

Comment: Свою ошибку понял. Тогда напишите пожалуйста, как установить начальное количество строк в гриде?